# Eliminar div cuando el checkbox está unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas,me gustaria saber como hacer para que cuando el checked esté unchecked el div checksolu se elimine.
He intentando hacer remove con un else pero no ha funcionado.
Gracias

```
 function showsolucion() {
            $('input[name=radiocheck]').one('click', function () { 
            if ($('input[id=mostrarcheck]').is(':checked')) {
                var checksolu = $("<textarea id='divsolucion' name='solu' rows='2' cols='45' autocomplete='off' required></textarea>");
                $("#consulta").append(checksolu);

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Si pusieras más información para reproducir el problema podría ayudarte con más facilidad. Por ahora te he puesto dos métodos de borrar el `textarea` que has creado a través de su `id` con `remove()` y vaciando al padre con `empty()`.

Comment: Hola Seyker, quieres eliminarlo del DOM o estaria bien que no sea visible, en ese caso se puede resolver sin codigo usando CSS. Hazme saber y te propongo una respuesta.

Answer (score 3):

Sin más código que me permite probar lo que quieres sólo puedo mostrarte dos formas de hacerlo:

```js
function comprobar1() {
  if ($('input[id=mostrarcheck]').is(':checked')) {
    var checksolu = $("<textarea id='divsolucion' name='solu' rows='2' cols='45' autocomplete='off' required></textarea>");
    $("#consulta").append(checksolu);
  } else {
    $("#consulta").empty();
  }
}

function comprobar2() {
  if ($('input[id=mostrarcheck]').is(':checked')) {
    var checksolu = $("<textarea id='divsolucion' name='solu' rows='2' cols='45' autocomplete='off' required></textarea>");
    $("#consulta").append(checksolu);
  } else {
    $("#divsolucion").remove();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p><input type="checkbox" id="mostrarcheck" checked> Hola</p>
<button onclick="comprobar1()">Borrar con empty()</button>
<button onclick="comprobar2()">Borrar con remove()</button>
<p><small>Nota: Tras agregar pulsando los botones de arriba desmarcar la opción para borrar.</small></p>
<div id="consulta"></div>
```

En la primera forma hago un `empty()` del `<div>` padre, eliminando todos sus hijos.

En la segunda selecciono el `<textarea>` cuyo `id` es `divsolucion` y lo elimino con `remove()`.

Ten en cuenta que si pulsas varias veces el botón y agregas varios `<textarea>`, la primera opción borrará todos al mismo tiempo ya que deja vacío el padre y la segunda opción los borrará uno a uno.

Answer (score 1):

Con CSS?

```css
.div{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background: red;
    display: none;
}

.check:checked~.div {
    display: block
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="check" checked="checked"> 

<div class="div"></div>
```